# MVC get child count in Index view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I used scaffolding to create the Index, Details, Create, Edit and Delete views and the controller. I have two view models (Parent / Child) relation. In my Index view I want to display the list of Teams as well as some information on the players (Parent / child). For example I want to display in the Index view the teams with the players count per team and last players that was modified. I am not sure where to begin. 
Example:
(Team) Red -- (Last Modified) 01/02/2015 -- (Number Players) 10   and so on.

Team ViewModel

```
public class TeamVM
 {
public int ID { get; set; }    
public string Name { get; set; }
public DateTime? LastActivity { get; set; }
public string NumberPlayers { get; set; }

public IList<PLayerVM> PlayerVM { get; set; }
}
```

Player ViewModel

```
public class PlayerVM
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public int TeamID { get; set; }

public string PlayerInfo { get; set; }
public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Other ViewModel

```
public class TeamViewModel
{
public List<Team> Teams{ get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{      
  TeamViewModelviewModel = new TeamViewModel();
  viewModel.Teams= db.Teams.ToList();

  return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Your controller does not match with your viewmodels, above can you show what you already have tried ?

Comment: My bad, I fixed it. I do not have much to show because I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Are your `VM`'s also your entities? Or are they mapped?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. In my controller I map my viewModels with my models and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.Products.ToList()`?? I assume that is where you mean `db.Teams.ToList()`?

You are using viewmodels, so you should map the db data to your viewmodels first:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
    var teams = db
        .Teams
        .Include("Players") // Assuming your Team entity has a collection of Players
        .SelectMany(t => new TeamVM { 
            ID = t.ID, 
            // etc.. 
        })
        .ToList();   
    return View(new TeamViewModel { Teams = teams });
}
```

model:

```
public class TeamVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastActivity { get; set; }

    public IList<PLayerVM> PlayerVM { get; set; }

    public int NumberPlayers { 
        get { return PlayerVM.Count(); }
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model MyProject.Models.TeamViewModel

<table>
@foreach(var team in Model.Teams.ToList()) {
    <tr>
        <td>@team.Name</td> // Name
        <td>@team.NumberPlayers</td> // Playercount
        <td>@team.PlayerVM.Max(p => p.LastActivity).LastActivity</td> // Last edited
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, I meant Teams. Sorry.

Comment: The NumberPlayers property is only assigned in my viewModel and not my model. I do not want to save this to the database. When I added -- public int NumberPlayers { 
        get { return PlayerVM.Count(); }
    } -- I get the following error:  Property or indexer 'NumberNote' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Are you assigning to it? Are you setting it when you SelectMany()?

Comment: @devqon, this did not answer my question completely. However, I was able to grab some pieces from your answer to make me solve my issues therefore, I will make this as answered. Thanks.